# Where is the Yellow Nameless Soul?

Tags: prinny-2

In Prinny 2: Dawn of Operation Panties, which map/time is the Yellow Soul found in, and whereabouts is it? I'm pretty sure that's the Dimension Guide's soul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the Nether Valley. I got it at the latest possible time with the Owl. However I don't think time matters, I found an orb in every "main" level.

In the level it's right after you enter the first "cave", above a ceiling of boxes very early in the level. Orbs aren't nearly as well hidden in this game as they were in the first.